# JS, PHP, How to paginate Text in response to the Mobile Browser screen size?

Tags: javascript, text, browser, screen-size, pagination

I want to use this simple slideshows script from Jsfiddle.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/JB22E/3/
```

Its optimized for mobile browsers (sliding left or right).

The individual pages are appearing in horizontal order like in an E-Book Reader.

Below in the example, the Text from id="article1" exceeds the mobile browser screen size.

I want the second and third paragraph, to get automatically transferred into id="article2", id="article3" etc.

I have a JS Variable named $HtmlText.

Which contains only the entire Lorem Ipsum Text (with Tags).

The other Html Code must be created dynamically with Javascript...

Questions

1.) How can I paginate Text in response to the viewer's screen size?

Is that possible with JS or PHP?

I looked into a similar question, but I can't figure out how to make it work...

I'm also new to this, so I would appreciate some help on this.

Thanks a lot.

```
<body>
<div id="article1">
<p>Some Text filling into Page1...</p>
<p>more Text exceeding Page1...</p>
<br>
<img src="/images/picture.jpg" />
<br>
<p>even more Text exceeding Page1, Page2 because of the image</p>
</div>


<div id="article2">
<p>more Text exceeding Page1...</p>
<br>
<img src="/images/picture.jpg" />
</div>


<div id="article3">
<p>even more Text exceeding Page1, Page2 because of the image</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You usually just use CSS to have the same thing show up differently on different platforms. If you want your desktop and mobile layouts to look the same, put the following in your `<head>`: `<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />`. Then just make sure you use a div directly within your `<body>` with a `width:940px; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;`. Well, you don't have to use padding. Bottom line, 980px width is respected by most Browsers.